# Position Fixed on internet explorer

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I want to fix my footer on the bottom of the page. It's working on internet explorer, and changing the doctype will change many things in my page so I can't use it.

Any other solutions?

```
.footer{
    width:100%;
    height:49px;
    background-image:url(../img/footer-bg.gif);
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    z-index:99;
    float:left;  
    overflow:hidden;
    position:fixed;
}
```

Comment: could you make a jsfiddle of some sample code we can use? also have you tried using `position: absolute;` and putting the footer directly inside of the body?

Comment: why change the Doctype? quirksmode days are over.

Comment: "changing the doctype will change many things in my page so I can't use it" — Changing the Doctype to one that triggers standards mode will, in the not-too-long run, save you far more time when fixing all the dependancies you have on bugs will cost you.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Changing the doctype **will** cause some issues with IE if that's what you're used to coding for, but that CSS seems like it should work fine in all other major browsers. Can you clarify what the problem is?

Answer (score -1):

you can use:

- html #element {
  position: absolute;
  top: expression(document.compatMode=="CSS1Compat"? document.documentElement.scrollTop+100+"px" : body.scrollTop+100+"px");
  }

Replace 100+"px"